# Convert EDI 214 and EDI 215 messages to XML using Smooks

Tags: edi, smooks

I am very new to EDI. I am trying to write a Spring boot java program to convert EDI 214 (Shipment Status) and EDI 215 (Motor Carrier Pickup Manifest) messages to XML using Smooks. Looking at EDI 214 data elements, I couldn't figure out a easy way to write EDI-to-XML mapping XML with all the data elements. Is there any easy way to get correct Smooks mapping XML.
Thanks,